# Where do I bind my service?

Tags: android, android-service

[image: Base Fragement Activity class]

I have a FragementActivity class that is sub classed into various activities. I have  service class that handles the communication between the phone and a device(BLE device). I do not know where do I bind the activity? In the base FramgmentActivity class? If so how will it work when I switch between activities ? Do I unbind every time because onCreate() will be called every time its subclass is called?

Comment: If your service isn't activity dependent you shouldn't bind it. If it needs to last the duration of your application you should look into a background service that runs with a notification. If it needs to be run at certain intervals or specific times and has a set process to run you might want to run an IntentService. The point of binding though is when the Service is dependent on the lifecycle of the Activity it is bound to.

Comment: The Service class is connecting to the device and sending and receiving messages between the phone and the device and that  is used by these activities . i.e. it is constantly waiting on messages from the GATT. and notifies on receiving to the phone. The base activity processes it and is used by subactivities.